# Deserialize XML string not working

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have this XML string

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <ITEMNO>1</ITEMNO>
    <PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE>
    <QTY>2</QTY>
    <CUSTPARTNO>469</CUSTPARTNO>
    <DESCRIPT>35W 1/4W 5%</DESCRIPT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ITEMNO>3</ITEMNO>
    <PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE>
    <QTY>5</QTY>
    <CUSTPARTNO>116</CUSTPARTNO>
    <DESCRIPT>1.74K 1/8W 1% Film</DESCRIPT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ITEMNO>2</ITEMNO>
    <PARTSOURCE>MAKE</PARTSOURCE>
    <QTY>5</QTY>
    <CUSTPARTNO>651321</CUSTPARTNO>
    <DESCRIPT>Make Part</DESCRIPT>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

I am trying to Deserialize it into this `Root` class

```
public class Root
{
    public BOMItems Row { get; set; }
}
public class BOMItems
{
    public string ITEMNO { get; set; }
    public string USED { get; set; }
    public string PARTSOURCE { get; set; }
    public string QTY { get; set; }
    public string CUSTPARTNO { get; set; }
    public string CREV { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPT{ get; set; }
}
```

Using this method:

```
public Root TransformXMLToClass(string pXml)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(pXml));

    return (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

This works only on the first node.

I have tried changing the `Root` class like this:

```
    public List<BOMItems> Row{get;set;}
```

It didn't work for any of the nodes

How do I get it to deserialize all nodes?

Comment: you should add "XmlElement" during the serialization process.. Decorate your properties in BOM Class with [XmlElement]

Comment: huh? Can you provide more details?  Where?

Comment: see the below answer for serialization

Comment: On a side note, you could try to use XDoc with latest versions of dot net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it's quite simple. You just need to tell the serializer how to handle the collection of elements.

You do need to have the property as a collection or array like this:

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("Row")]
    public BOMItems[] Row { get; set; }
}
```

The "[XmlElement]" is what will tell it how to deserialize correctly. Adding the XmlElementAttribute tells the serializer to treat it as a "flat" sequence.

```
<!-- Row Elements Flattened -->
<Root>
  <Row>
    <ITEMNO>1</ITEMNO>
    <PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE>
    <QTY>2</QTY>
    <CUSTPARTNO>469</CUSTPARTNO>
    <DESCRIPT>35W 1/4W 5%</DESCRIPT>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ITEMNO>3</ITEMNO>
    <PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE>
    <QTY>5</QTY>
    <CUSTPARTNO>116</CUSTPARTNO>
    <DESCRIPT>1.74K 1/8W 1% Film</DESCRIPT>
  </Row>
</Root>

    <!-- Versus Row Elements Unflattened -->
<Root>
  <Row>
    <BOMItems>
      <ITEMNO>1</ITEMNO>
      <PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE>
      <QTY>2</QTY>
      <CUSTPARTNO>469</CUSTPARTNO>
      <DESCRIPT>35W 1/4W 5%</DESCRIPT>
    </BOMItems>
    <BOMItems>
      <ITEMNO>3</ITEMNO>
      <PARTSOURCE>Buy</PARTSOURCE>
      <QTY>5</QTY>
      <CUSTPARTNO>116</CUSTPARTNO>
      <DESCRIPT>1.74K 1/8W 1% Film</DESCRIPT>
    </BOMItems>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I had tried that before.  Perhaps was just because I didn't decorate it first.

Comment: Glad I could help. The serializer is very useful, but sometimes it's takes some work to make your classes match the input. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.71).aspx for useful information on using attributes to control it.

Comment: @Xenophile: Good answer. But, using [XmlElement] for Row works, but I tried giving [XmlElement("Root")] doesn't work..Any ideas why?

Comment: @now: I'm not sure I understand the question. Applying [XmlElement] to an array or List<> will flatten it so that each item in the array is it's own tag. It's an alternate use for the [XmlElement] attribute. It eliminates the container tag which the serializer usually looks for. Without it, the required xml would look similar to what you see in my second example of xml.

Comment: @Xenophile: Could you tell me what you mean by "flattening" with a simple example ?

Comment: @now: look at the 2 xml snippets I included. The first one is "flattened", so you see multiple "Row" tags. The second one is not flattened. You will see a "Row" tag which is the tag for the Row array property itself and then the serializer will serialize each object in the array with it's own tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your BOM class should be something like below,

```
[XmlElement("ITEMNO")]
public string ITEMNO { get; set; }
```

so as to inform the serializer that you read ITEMNO and save it in the ITEMNO

EDIT: 
It has to be done for every property of BOM class.

Answer: (with the list )

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("Row")]
    public List<BOMItems> Row { get; set; }
}
public class BOMItems
{
    [XmlElement("ITEMNO")]
    public string ITEMNO { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("USED")]
    public string USED { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("PARTSOURCE")]
    public string PARTSOURCE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTY")]
    public string QTY { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CUSTPARTNO")]
    public string CUSTPARTNO { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CREV")]
    public string CREV { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("DESCRIPT")]
    public string DESCRIPT { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("c:\\tet.xml")));

        var serializedOutput = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: It still only gets the first node

Comment: As per my description, I did do it before adding the decorations.  I will try that.  Unrelated, your suggestion did fix another issue I had, but so far, not my main concern.

Comment: Just as before List<BOMItems> prevents it from loading even the first node.

Comment: Actually, it shall work if you do something like below: [XmlElement]
        public List<BOMItems> Row { get; set; }

Comment: Already tried that too, no difference in the results.  It had to be an array